# C++ Redistributable required for private deployment of SQL Compact 4.0?

Tags: sql-server-ce

Is msvcr90.dll (the C++ redistributable included in the SQL Compact 4.0 *Private* folder) required for a private deployment of SQL Compact 4.0? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is required on the system, so if you know it is already there (Because 3.5 SP1 is installed), you can exclude it - but why take the chance? See http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html for more info